# 3 div's in a container

Tags: html, css, position

First I have to say, I didn't find any answer to this. If it's a duplicate, please forgive me and point me correct.

I'm trying to create a div with three divs inside. The center div should have text, and the side divs should have a vertically centered line, like this:

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div className="container">
  <div class="line"><hr/></div>
  <div class="text">My Text</div>
  <div class="line"><hr/></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  .text {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .line {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

My problem is that I don't see the lines at all, my text is positioned to the left. I tried `margin: auto;` but that didn't help me. Can someone plese help?

I have one prerequisite, I can't use flexboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this layout using `pseudoelements` instead of `hr`.

Example:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: grey;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.text {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  /* add left and right padding if needed */
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">My Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm I don't see the line at all. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Never mind, it works when I try it by itself but not inside other elements.